# Automatically refresh page if widget is added to page?

Tags: php, functions, customization, javascript

I have a function which detects change to the site, and refreshes the page if it has changed. This works perfectly with everything except when adding widgets to it. I go to Customizer and Widgets, and add a widget, then press Publish and it will not detect this change and it won't refresh.

This is the function that does the job (works for post changes, images, style settings in Customizer etc.):

```
function get_post_status_hash() {
    global $post;
    $data = array();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'slide',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => theme_get_slide_order(),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        if ( show_post_today( $post->ID ) && show_post_at_this_time( $post->ID ) ) {
            $data[] = $post->ID.":".$post->post_modified;
        }
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    $data[] = serialize(get_theme_mods());
    return md5(implode(";", $data));
}
```

And this is placed in the footer.php

```
<script>
                var postModified='<?=get_post_status_hash()?>';
</script>
```

This is the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var contentChangeCheckInterval = typeof defaultContentChangeCheckInterval !== 'undefined' ? defaultContentChangeCheckInterval : 10 * 1000;
    greetCheckModifiedContent(contentChangeCheckInterval);
    setStatusText('OK');
});

function greetCheckModifiedContent(modifiedContentCheckInterval) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        //console.log('Checking for content change...');
        jQuery.get({
            url  : statusUrl
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data != postModified) {
                console.log('Content has changed, reloading page...');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url  : "/",
                    type : "HEAD"
                })
                .done(function() {
                    setStatusText('Reloading');
                    location.reload();
                })
                .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    setStatusText('HEAD check failed: ' + textStatus);
                    console.log('Unable to reload: ' + textStatus + ', trying again in ' + modifiedContentCheckInterval + " ms");
                    greetCheckModifiedContent(modifiedContentCheckInterval);
                });
            } else {
                setStatusText('OK');
                greetCheckModifiedContent(modifiedContentCheckInterval)
            }
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            setStatusText('Status check failed: ' + textStatus);
            greetCheckModifiedContent(modifiedContentCheckInterval)
        });
    }, modifiedContentCheckInterval);
}
```

How come the widgets aren't detected?

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests they should be? It looks like your data is a hash of the post modified date and the theme mods, neither of which includes widgets. Widget positions are stored as the `sidebars_widgets` option, and widget data is stored for each widget in `widget_{id_base}` in `wp_options` for each widget type. Even with all that you can't know which widgets are used on which page until after the page has rendered. Seems to me a simpler solution would be to to just use `wp_remote_get()` and compare the HTML. Either way this isn't very performant. What's the point of this?

Comment: I just added the javascript which does the refresh. And what I want to acheive is that the page is reloaded using the function above if any change is made in the Customizer to the Widgets.